# Загрузка произвольных полей Wordpress по клику пользователя (ajax, js)

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Всем привет

Столкнулся с проблемой. Нужно в тексте записи по клику мышки пользователя загрузить кусок текста из произвольного поля. Перегуглил всё, нашел одно лишь решение на весь интернет.

Делал, как сказано тут — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600231/wordpress-load-custom-field-in-ajax

В functions.php вставил:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_load_custom_field_data','load_custom_field_data');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_custom_field_data','load_custom_field_data');

function load_custom_fields_data(){
$postid=$_POST['postid'];
$metakey= $_POST['metakey'];
echo get_post_meta($postid,$metakey,true);
die();
}
```

В шаблон записи вставил следующее:

```
<a class="get_meta_val" postid="<?php echo $post->ID?>" metakey ="your_meta_key">Get Custom Value</a>
//get postid in any way you want and put you customfield name in your_meta_key

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    jQuery(document).one('click','.get_meta_val',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var pid = jQuery(this).attr('postid');
        var metakey = jQuery(this).attr('metakey');
        var data = {
            'action': 'load_custom_field_data',
            'postid': pid,
            'metakey':metakey
        };
        // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert('Custom Field Value is: ' + response);
            //Here you can do whatever you want with your returned value
        });
        });
});
</script>
```

Заменил соответственно your_meta_key на своё произвольное поле.

Но в итоге вывелась синяя подчеркнутая ссылка, но кликнуть на ней нельзя (курсор при наведении становится, как будто на текст навёл и по клику ничего не происходит)

Выглядит итоговая ссылка в коде так:

```
<a class="get_meta_val" postid="5273" metakey ="kusoktexta">Get Custom Value</a>
```

Где может быть ошибка? Такое ощущение, что скрипт не подгружается

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: `jQuery(document).one(...` у вас тут опечатка, `on` должно быть ане `one`. Впрочем хорошо бы еще атрибуты в ссылке заменить на `data-postid` и `data-metakey` и получать их через `jQuery(this).data('postid')`

Comment: @teran, нет, [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) — это не ошибка

Comment: В приведенном вами фрагменте кода ошибок нет. Вероятно, ошибка где-то в другом месте, попробуйте найти ее через инструменты разработчика в браузере (CTRL+SHIFT+I в Chrome и Firefox). Ошибка может вывестись (при загрузке страницы, или при нажатии по кнопке) в консоль в инструментах разработчика

Comment: @Crantisz век живи - век учись :)

Answer (score 0):

В функшнс:

```
function func_my_aj() {
echo $_POST['id'];
echo $_POST['metakey'];
echo $_POST['postid'];
$postid=$_POST['postid'];
$metakey= $_POST['metakey'];
echo get_post_meta($postid,$metakey,true);
die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_my_aj', 'func_my_aj');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_aj', 'func_my_aj');
```

В теме:

```
<script>jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
$('body').on('click', '.link-aj', function(){
i =$( this ).data('id'); 
met =$( this ).attr('metakey'); 
pid = $(this).attr('postid');
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", 
data: {
action: 'my_aj',
'id':i,
'metakey':met,
'postid': pid,
},
success: function(html){
$('.result').html(html); 
},
})
});
});
</script>
<span class="link-aj" data-id="222" metakey ="es-telegram" postid="<?php echo $post->ID?>">кликни 222</span>
<span class="link-aj" data-id="555" metakey ="es-telegram" postid="<?php echo $post->ID?>">кликни 555</span>
<span class="result">тут появится контент</span>
```

Работает, только лишнее вырезать.
У меня задача была по клику (при смене языка) менять одну кнопку на другую.